# Magento 2.3 recaptcha not available as described in official guide

Tags: magento2.3, recaptcha

Official Magento documentation mentions Recaptcha feature can be found in Stores > Configuration > security

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/stores/security-google-recaptcha.html

No such option exists. Guide does not mention if requires commerce or specific version of Magento or that any additional software is required.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, bad question. Module was disabled